# Distribution of Even Number of Successes of Bernoulli trials

Tags: stochastic-processes, bernoulli-distribution

Let pn be the prob thatn bernoulli trials results in an even number of successes. Find the pgf of {pn}.  Hence obtain an expression for pn. Also find an asymptotic valus of pn using partial fraction theorem

Comment: For answer to first part, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899491/bernoulli-trials-n-p-probability-for-even-odd-number-of-successes).